# Connection (offline) to OracleDB on CentOSVM using Vbox doesn't work

Tags: oracle, ubuntu, centos7, vbox

First of all, I am no developer or network specialist, so please keep things simple. Here's my basic situation:

I have a local server (Apache on Ubuntu 20.04) with several vhosts that need to connect to a Oracle-DB that's installed on a VBox CentOS VM. I do a lot of travel, so the IP I use to connect to the internet changes almost daily, and sometimes I have no internet connection at all. A colleague set my system up to be able to connect via static IP, but unfortunately yesterday something happeneded (vBox went into guru-mode and never got out it) and I had to reinstall and set up the whole thing. But it doesn't work.

As the above mentioned colleague isn't available anymore, I need some external help. Here's what I have:

- VBox on Ubuntu, with a host-only adapter set up to have a static IP (192.168.56.10), DHCP off and another bridged adapter
- VM with CentOS 7 (system for the Oracle DB)

ifcofig of that VM:

- enp0s3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
  inet 192.168.43.121  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.43.255
  inet6 fe80::5255:9ce9:96c4:7810  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20
  ether 08:00:27:b2:8b:0d  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
  RX packets 43  bytes 4140 (4.0 KiB)
  RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
  TX packets 69  bytes 7329 (7.1 KiB)
  TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
- enp0s8: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
  inet **192.168.56.5**  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.56.255
  inet6 fe80::6408:c9ff:7c9a:dfb0  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20
  ether 08:00:27:52:35:de  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
  RX packets 1  bytes 590 (590.0 B)
  RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
  TX packets 38  bytes 5225 (5.1 KiB)
  TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp0s8 is the one that connects to the host-only adapter, and it's configured to have a static IP (192.168.56.10). Yet, after restarting the VM it shows with another IP.

Regardless of this I can't connect via SQLDeveloper (on the host) other than using the IP of enp0s3, and only while I'm connected to the internet (wireless) and the provider doesn't change the IP. It wouldn't be a grate deal to change that IP everytime I start to work, but I have 4 different DBs and sometimes 3 or 4 local websites that have their own config files to connect to the DBs.

**Short:** I need a way to connect from my host to the Oracle DB on the VM without having to change the configuration files of my vhosts or SQLDeveloper.

I will gladly post any further information you may need, but I'm a new user and apparently not allowed to post pics/screenshots yet.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Skip all this networking futzing and setup port forwards. You can tell VirtualBox to map port 1521 on your host to port 1521 on the vm, so SQL Developer can simply connect to localhost:1521/database in your connection.

[image]

[I talk about this in more details here](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2014/03/connecting-to-oracle-from-your-host-to-a-virtualbox-oel-guest/)

*Disclaimer: I'm the product manager at Oracle for SQL Developer.*